# How can I show my username when I commit my github repository using git command line tool

Tags: git, github

I recently created my own github account. i made a github repository using github webUI and then i copied repository cloned url and cloned in my local pc using git command line tool:

```
git clone <repo url>
```

then i enter in a cloned directory and add some new file

```
git add <filename>
```

after that i commit and push in my master repository.

```
git commit -m "add some comment"
git push -u origin master
```

**But** 
after that when i going to my github account and watch repository using webUI.
It's showing like this

[image]

I want my **GitHub** username would appear when I make any changes and do commit from git command line tool.
 **How can I do that?**

Good answer will be appreciated. Thanks !

Answer (score 4):

You should configure your username/email before next commit:

```
git config --global user.name "Your Username"
git config --global user.email "your_email@example.com"
```

More details at [Github setup documentation](https://help.github.com/categories/setup/). Note that email should be the same that you've pointed during registration.

Comment: I think it's best to configure the user name and email before committing, not pushing.

Comment: so, it will apply on specific repository or it will apply as a global settings of git command-line tool ?

Comment: `git config --global` will be applied for all repositories. For a specific repo, use `--local`  option. See more at https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config

Comment: umm, not sure --global i don't want for all but thanks @0xAX to point out me to GitHub documentation i didn't have that I hope there will be an answer in case of specific repository.